# Sitemesh3 custom properties

Tags: jsp, decorator, sitemesh, custom-properties

Currently I am trying custom properties to my decorator for additional javascript files for a specific template. In my decorator I have tried using:

```
<sitemesh:write property='div.testcontent' />
```

And in my JSP I tried:

```
<div class="testcontent">
  TEST CONTENT
</div>
```

I believe I need to add something to my sitemesh3.xml file in order for this to work. I saw that people have used:

```
<content-processor>
 <tag-rule-bundle class="org.sitemesh.content.tagrules.html.DivExtractingTagRuleBundle" />
</content-processor>
```

But I am unsure how to properly do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated!